# How to put version and build number in ejb-jar.xml

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I'm using Netbeans 8.0.2 and Glassfish 4.0 (and 4.1) to build a message driven bean.  I'm not using Maven (my choice would be to use it)

There is an article to put the revision and build number in the build.xml file (http://dragly.org/2009/10/11/revision-and-build-numbers-for-your-netbeans-apps/).  This is for a SE app and I'm not sure if it will work for an EJB and how.

I have a fixed version number but need to increment the build number.

1. Where and how do I put the version number (plus build number) in for an EJB? (It should be like 1.0.0.**buildNumber**) (searching for "ejb-jar.xml" plus version gives a lot of EJB version 2.x, 3.x results)
2. How do I access this number in my EJB? (I was thinking of accessing it as a resource in my class?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out:
For a jar (library, SE, etc) in the `build.xml` file, just before the closing `</project>` tag insert the following; Based on http://www.jug-muenster.de/versioning-and-signing-jar-files-in-netbeans-775/ : **Note:** The manifest file have a very specific format!

```
<target name="-pre-init">
    <property name="project.name" value="MySEProject" />
    <property name="document.title" value="My SE Project Specification" />
    <property name="document.version" value="1.0" />
    <property name="version.number" value="1.7.0" />
    <buildnumber file="build.num" />
    <tstamp>
        <format property="NOW" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z" />
    </tstamp>

    <exec outputproperty="svna.version" executable="svnversion">
        <arg value="-c" />
        <redirector>
            <outputfilterchain>
                <tokenfilter>
                    <replaceregex pattern="^[0-9]*:?" replace="" flags="g"/>
                    <replaceregex pattern="M" replace="" flags="g"/>
                </tokenfilter>
            </outputfilterchain>
        </redirector>
    </exec>

    <!-- Add the version information to the manifest file -->
    <manifest file="${manifest.file}">
        <attribute name="Package-Title" value="MyCompany/${project.name}" />
        <attribute name="Specification-Title" value="${document.title}" />
        <attribute name="Specification-Version" value="${document.version}" />
        <attribute name="Specification-Vendor" value="MyCompany" />
        <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="${project.name}" />
        <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="${halo.version.number}.${build.number}" />
        <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="MyCompany" />
        <attribute name="Revision" value="${svna.version}" />
        <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}" />
        <attribute name="Built-Date" value="${NOW}" />
    </manifest>
</target>

<target name="-post-jar">
    <delete file="${manifest.file}" />
</target>
```

And for an EJB.  In the (ABC) Enterprise Application folder, edit the `build.xml` file the same as above, the target tag name change to `pre-dist` *as well as* the manifest tag `<manifest file="${meta.inf}/MANIFEST.MF">`.

Furthermore for EJB, to be able to programmable read the version number, edit the `build.xml` file in the ABC-ejb folder (where ABC is the ejb project name).  The target name change to `-post-init`.

The code to read it out (you get all the manifest files from all the libraries you include, thus you have to hunt for your one - maybe a better way will be to look at the URL?):

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.jar.Manifest;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author TungstenX
 */
public class VersionInfo {
    private static final Logger LOG =    Logger.getLogger(VersionInfo.class.getName());
    private static final String PROJECT = "MySEProject";
    private static final String COMPANY = "MyCompany";
    private static Manifest MANIFEST;

    /**
     * Get the version number from the manifest file
     * @return The version number or '--'
     */
    public static String GetVersionNumber() {
        if (MANIFEST == null) {
            try {
                Enumeration<URL> resources = VersionInfo.class.getClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
                while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
                    URL url = resources.nextElement();
                    try(InputStream is = url.openStream()) {
                        Manifest tmpManifest = new Manifest(is);
                        for (Object o : tmpManifest.getMainAttributes().keySet()) {
                            if (o.toString().equals("Package-Title") 
                                    && tmpManifest.getMainAttributes().getValue(o.toString()).startsWith(COMPANY)
                                    && tmpManifest.getMainAttributes().getValue(o.toString()).endsWith(PROJECT)) {
                                MANIFEST = tmpManifest;
                            } 
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error while reading manifest files: {0}", e.toString());
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error while reading manifest files: {0}", e.toString());
            }
        }
        if(MANIFEST != null) {
            return MANIFEST.getMainAttributes().getValue("Implementation-Version");
        } else {
            return "--";
        }
    }
```

**Note:** The difference in target name and location of `MANIFEST.MF` file!